# What model should I use for multiple time series input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, rnn

I want to predict bacteria plate count in the water from time series(around 10000 values in a row) of water temperature on a one minute granularity, and other **daily** climate data including min and max temperature, rainfall, solar exposure, day_of_the_week etc for a sequence of 20 days each before the sample was collected for test. There are 700 different locations in the building.

My initial approach was to join all time series of the same location into one row/one series. I used RNN LSTM but the testing accuracy is not so good(65%-75%). I guess the reason could be that joining different time series(eg. water temperature and rainfall) may have led to gradient explosion due to the contrasting nature of data, thus I tried gradient clipping and there was no improvement in testing accuracy. I understand that in general RNN is good for time series data and CNN is good for image preprocessing. But my case is slightly different as I'm having multiple time series joined together to form one time series. I'm wondering if CNN or GRU would be a better model to use.

The data looks like this:

```
     x0  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5   ... x10000 Date       max_t1...max_t20 min_t1...min_t20 rf1... rf20 sol1...sol20 d_wk1... d_wk20
1    40 31.05  25.5 25.5 25.5 25   ...  33    2019-01-01 26.2  ...        20.2  ...         0 ...      32.4...       4 ...
2    35  35.75 36.5 36.5 36.5 36.5 ...  29    2019-01-03 24.8. ...        18.4  ...         0 ...      28.8          6 ...
⋮     ⋮   ⋮      ⋮    ⋮    ⋮     ⋮          ⋮
```

where

max_t1, ..., max_t20 represent max temperature from day1 to day20(`Date` day);

min_t1, ..., min_t20 represent min temperature from day1 to day20(`Date` day);

rf1, ..., rf20 represent rainfall from day1 to day20(`Date` day);

sol1, ..., sol20 represent solar exposure from day1 to day20(`Date` day).

d_wk1, ..., d_wk20 represent which day it was of the week from day1 to day20(`Date` day)

These are all the features beside water temperature data(so there are around 100 new columns in total).

---

Update Of Question:

I have checked many CNN case studies online but very few are on non-image data. I fit the data using CNN on Keras but the accuracy level is very low(<60%). What could go wrong? Is there anything I can do? A friend suggested `XGBoost`- is there a way to apply the algorithm to my data? Any idea is appreciated.

So far I've used something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(merge.iloc[:,1:10170], merge[['Result_cat','Result_cat1']].values, test_size=0.2) 

import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape=(10167,))) 
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='softmax')) 
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) 


model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10000, epochs=1000)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=10000)
```

Comment: Did you gather the climate data on your own or do you use a weather database?

Comment: @nilsinelabore what is your data like? Can you share samples of the data you have (and the target values)?

Comment: @Ben I downloaded the daily climate date from Bureau of Meteorology

Comment: @serali hi I've added a sample of the data in my original question

Comment: Can't you download the data with a different time interval?

Comment: @Ben Unfortunately daily data is the smallest time interval data available to me at the moment...

Comment: there are other databases with hourly time steps

Comment: @Ben Do you think that would make a better model? Where can I find the hourly data?

Comment: I like https://rp5.ru/Weather_in_the_world I don't know if it would make the model better as I lack knowledge about the ongoing processes but it is probably worth a try.

Comment: @Ben thank you for sharing that resources. May I ask for your opinion on the validity of using CNN in such a time series made of multiple ones based on your experience? Are there any models that might fit this situation better? Thanks

Comment: I'm in the topic of analyzing time series data only for some months and I'm working on some methods as well but my goals are different. When you use DL for analyzing time series I would consider LSTMs and afterwards I would have a look at CNNs, so, yeah, I would behave the same ;) I just wonder why your LSTMs did not perform well. Contrary, I can't judge whether you need DL at all. You might have a look at ARIMA / Kalman as well. Especially in a combination with DL this might be a powerful tool.

Comment: When my DL is not performing well (Autoencoder), I will combine it with a LSTM and when this still is not doing good, I will add ARIMA / Kalman to it. Probably as a kind of ensemble. You could also check out XGBoost which seems very promising as well. It is also on my list.

Comment: @Ben thank you for your suggestions and sorry for the late reply. A reason why RNN didn't do well I think might be that the water temperature experiences fluctuations as the tap is turned on(a spike with a sharp rise and gradual decrease) which is a random event. That's why I was hoping DL could extract some underlying patterns with multiple neurone layers. ARIMA / Kalman sound like something I could try, but I've never used them in DL before. Do you know of any relevant resources or online case studies I can study? Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please add some plots so that we can get some impressions about what is going on? I think a sharp rise will always be a problem but I can't realize its meaning. ARIMA/Kalman isn't meant to be added to a NN, it is something on its own but actually I doubt you will benefit from it. I think I would continue to study the AE-LSTM. But hard to tell from the distance..

Answer (score 0):

You mention having 2 types of data:

- Water temperature with a minute-granularity
- Climate data taken 20 days prior

I'm not sure what you mean with "joining the series into one row/series", but I don't think that it make sense to combine these two types as the time-frame is just too different. In this case it would probably be better to combine different layers to deal with the discrepancy. I would use a RNN layer for the water temperature and experiment with different layers (for example regular dense layers) for the remaining input, treating it as fixed inputs (like the location variable) instead of dynamic time-step input like the water temperature.

Since the climate data is 20 days prior, I don't think that it'll really influence the water temperature on a minute basis; the climate data is more like a foundation, similar to  the location variable.

Comment: thank you for the answer.By "joining the series into one row/series" I mean lay out various time series side by side, eg. water temp time series, rainfall time series etc. I agree that `time-frame is just too different` when combining time different features and there's great disparity in sample size. I want to mention that `climate data` consists of time series of max, min daily temperature, daily rainfall and solar exposure, each is a time series. (The hypothesis is that the climate data of all 20days prior to the date when sample was collected would affect bacteria growth)

Comment: My questions are: 1. Is there a way to model the data if I join all features in a row(before that, it is valid to do this?)? 2. Can I put the different input data in separate layers of RNN?(I'm new to neural network) 3. If yes, how can I do it? Could you maybe share some online examples? Thanks